# Opera and Firefox give me different contexts

Tags: javascript

I got this code:

```
var config = {};
config.knock = {
    self:null,
    init : function(){
       self = this;
       console.log(self)
    }
};

$(document).ready( function(){
     config.knock.init();
});
```

Firefox (8) tells me self is the config.knock object, but Opera (11.00) tells its Window object. Who's correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`self` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self) is a property of the `window` object. It seems that Opera does not allow to override it.

As you are not declaring your variable with `var`, this

```
self = this;
```

is the same as

```
window.self = this;
```

in your case.

You either want `var self`, or, if you want to refer to `config.knock.self`, either `config.knock.self` or `this.self`.

In Firefox as well as in Opera, `this` will refer to `config.knock`.

Comment: I created self to store a context-agnostic reference to the config.knock object, so If I use config.knock.self is totally redundant. I'll change the name of self.